# Excel Macros - FindAll and allow user to select result

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet with all the SKUs in our inventory. There are about 1300 records.Lot of the SKUs have similar numbers with only small variants for colour etc

I already have some code that will find the string entered by the user. My question is how to I present the list to the user and allow him to pick one SKU which I can use an input.

For example, imagine my database as:

```
Shirt-red
Shirt-Blue
Shirt-Pink
Trouser-red
Trouser-blue
```

If the user enters the string Shirt I want to present the user with Shirt-red, Shirt-Blue & Shirt-Pink and allow the user to select one of the 3 options which I will use for further processing

Thanks

Comment: Do a Find loop and add each result to a listbox, then the user can quickly see all of the results and select an item from the listbox.  If preferred, a listbox can be set to MultiSelect so that more than one result can be selected.  (Though that is assuming you're using a Userform, which I recommend for something like this)

Comment: I already tried that. I added the list box as per:
http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/list-box.html

But this list box is always visible on the sheet. I want the user experiance to be similar to the find all in excel. The results are displayed, selected by user and then the list box disappears. Also There are no cancel buttons on the list box. What happens if someone enters the wrong search string is presented with the results but not able to cancel and try again

Comment: Please clarify your question with a *specific* problem statement, preferably also including your code (a minimum amount needed to replicate your problem).

Comment: "Already tried that" doesn't give us much information.  When you tried it, did you run into a problem or error? Do you have code for how you tried to populate it so that we can review the code and offer suggestions to correct or improve it?

Comment: Set rngSearch = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A1320")
Set rngLast = rngSearch.Cells(rngSearch.Cells.Count)
Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find("573", After:=rngLast, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
'if "string" is found in search range:
 If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
strFirstAddress = rngFound.Address
Do
            'HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO DISPLAY THE RESULTS AND USE THE INPUT SELECTED BY THE USER TO PROCEED FURTHER
        Loop Until rngFound.Address = strFirstAddress
End If

Comment: I used the following code to populate the list box
With Sheet1.ListBox1
    .AddItem rngFound.Value
End With

The problem is the list box is always there on the sheet. I want a pop up window to display the results and allow the user to choose 1 results and for the windows to close and proceed to the next action

Comment: For this, you will want a Userform, not Sheet controls. Here is a [text tutorial](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/userform.html) and a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5oXcct1mOUw) that you can follow for how to create a basic userform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For tutorials on how to create a basic userform, here is a [text tutorial](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/userform.html) and a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5oXcct1mOUw).

Note that on the userform you create, I suggest the following names for the controls:

- Textbox: `txtFind`
- Find button: `btnFind`
- Listbox: `listResults`

Once you have your userform with a Textbox that the user can type into for what they want to search for, a Find button, and a Listbox, you would use this code for your Find button:

```
Private Sub btnFind_Click()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aData As Variant
    Dim vData As Variant
    Dim aResults() As Variant
    Dim lIndex As Long
    Dim sFind As String

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    sFind = Me.txtFind.Text
    Me.listResults.Clear

    With ws.Range("A2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        If .Row < 2 Then
            Me.txtFind.SetFocus
            MsgBox "No data in " & ws.Name
            Exit Sub
        End If
        aData = .Value
        ReDim aResults(1 To WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Cells, "*" & sFind & "*"), 1 To 1)
    End With

    lIndex = 0
    For Each vData In aData
        If InStr(1, vData, sFind, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            lIndex = lIndex + 1
            aResults(lIndex, 1) = vData
        End If
    Next vData

    If lIndex > 0 Then Me.listResults.List = aResults

End Sub
```

Comment: As a side note, the reason I iterate over an array instead of using a Find Loop is that in general iterating over an array is going to be much faster than a Find Loop.

Comment: wouldn't that `If .Row < 2 Then` be `If .Rows.Count < 2 Then`?

Comment: No, because it's assuming row 1 is a header row, and if there's no data in column A, the range would be A2:A1 which still results in a .rows.count of 2, but the .row would be 1 because it is the starting row, indicating that nothing was found in column A.

Comment: if my currently active sheet has values in cells "A1:A8" and run from immediate window `Range("A1", Cells(activesheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Row`, it returns `1`

Comment: aha, but A1 is header row. I only know understand that. sorry

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try it out and work tomorrow and let you know how successful i've been. I wasn't aware that it is possible to add a listbox in a userform and not as a sheet control.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Userform was the way to go. Also I replaced my find code with your suggestion. I'm using the Array now.